# Как к имеющемуся Python3-коду транслитератора украинского в латиницу прикрутить два нестандартных преобразования?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как правильно (не нарушая основного алгоритма замены) прикрутить к имеющемуся коду транслитератора украинского в латиницу 2 следующих преобразования?

1. Преобразование букв "Є", "Ї", "Й", "Ю", "Я" в "Ye", "Yi", "Y", "Yu", "Ya" соответственно (но лишь в том, случае, если эти буквы находятся на первой позиции в слове).
2. Преобразование сочетания букв "зг" в "zgh" в любой позиции в слове.

Во всех случаях регистр следующей буквы должен учитываться, чтобы не получалось что-либо вроде: "ЗГУРОВСКАЯ - ZghUROVSKAIA".

Об алгоритме замены:

Выделяются в отдельный словарь те украинские буквы, которые представляются в виде сразу нескольких латинских символов, после чего по циклу создается словарь (таблица транслитерации) из пар символов, где для каждой из таких букв (Є, Ж, Х, Ц, Ч, Ш, Щ, Ю и Я) есть варианты с каждой из строчных букв русского алфавита. Соответственно, остаётся сначала сделать замену для таких пар символов, а затем для всех остальных символов, которые остались не транслитерированы. Каждая из букв, соответствующих нескольким латинским буквам, после которой следует строчный символ ([а-я]) заменяется на латинское представление данной буквы, после которого следует тот же строчный символ (без транслитерации). После этого, соответственно, оставшиеся строчные буквы заменяются отдельно, как, впрочем, и прописные. При замене прописных букв, соответствующих нескольким латинским символам, для латинского представления буквы применяется метод upper(). В двух циклах, где для замены не используются регулярные выражения, операция замены производится с помощью строкового метода replace.

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/popoff/3ba4e1fd259eec19163a81221dc8609d/raw/f39c6041427ec06beebb6674ef140eb06af28ce4/ukr_translit_v1.py

Comment: Интересная история. Теперь сформулируйте ваш вопрос.

Comment: Сформулировал. Спасибо

Comment: алгоритм замены отдельных символов можно заменить на `translated = text.translate(dict(zip(map(ord, "ЄЖ"), ('Ye', 'Zh'))))`. Кстати, если решение в приведённом ответе сработало для вас, то [отметьте ответ галочкой](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы работаете с транслитерацией, согласно официального кабминовского документа (http://zakon4.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/55-2010-%D0%BF?test=4/UMfPEGznhhAUw.ZibfoNSdHI4cYs80msh8Ie6), то у Вас есть неправильные замены. Еще нужно учитывать позицию буквы. И наличие дефиса.
Могу предложить приблизительный вариант (правда, без регулярки, еще не освоил).

```
table = {
    'А': 'A',
    'Б': 'B',
    'В': 'V',
    'Г': 'H',
    'Ґ': 'G',
    'Д': 'D',
    'Е': 'E',
    'Є': 'Ye',
    'Ж': 'Zh',
    'З': 'Z',
    'Зг': 'Zgh',
    'ЗГ': 'ZGH',
    'И': 'Y',
    'I': 'I',
    'Ї': 'Yi',
    'Й': 'Y',
    'К': 'K',
    'Л': 'L',
    'М': 'M',
    'Н': 'N',
    'О': 'O',
    'П': 'P',
    'Р': 'R',
    'С': 'S',
    'Т': 'T',
    'У': 'U',
    'Ф': 'F',
    'Х': 'Kh',
    'Ц': 'Ts',
    'Ч': 'Ch',
    'Ш': 'Sh',
    'Щ': 'Shch',
    'Ю': 'Yu',
    'Я': 'Ya',
    'а': 'a',
    'б': 'b',
    'в': 'v',
    'г': 'h',
    'ґ': 'g',
    'д': 'd',
    'е': 'e',
    'є': 'ie',
    'ж': 'zh',
    'з': 'z',
    'зг': 'zgh',
    'и': 'y',
    'i': 'i',
    'ї': 'i',
    'й': 'i',
    'к': 'k',
    'л': 'l',
    'м': 'm',
    'н': 'n',
    'о': 'o',
    'п': 'p',
    'р': 'r',
    'с': 's',
    'т': 't',
    'у': 'u',
    'ф': 'f',
    'х': 'kh',
    'ц': 'ts',
    'ч': 'ch',
    'ш': 'sh',
    'щ': 'shch',
    'ю': 'iu',
    'я': 'ia',
    'Ь': '',
    "'": ""
    }

def upperlower(z):
    if z[1] == 0: return table[z[0].lower()].lower()
    if z[1] == 1: return table[z[0].lower()].upper()

def ua_in_lat(text):
    text_list = []
    n = 0
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i].islower():
            i1 = 0
        else:
            i1 = 1
        if i != len(text) - 1 and (text[i]+text[i+1]).lower() == 'зг':
            if text[i+1] == 'г': i1 = 0
            text_list.append((text[i]+text[i+1], i1))
            n = 1
        elif n == 1:
            n = 0
            continue
        else:
            text_list.append((text[i], i1))
    if text_list[1][1]:
        text_lat_def = table[text_list[0][0]].upper()
    else:
        text_lat_def = table[text_list[0][0]]
    for i in text_list[1:]:
        text_lat_def += upperlower(i)
    return text_lat_def

text_ua = 'ЗГУРОВСКАЯ-Згуровская-Язгуровская'
text_lat_list = []

if '-' in text_ua:
    for z in text_ua.split('-'):
        text_lat_list.append(ua_in_lat(z))
    text_lat = '-'.join(text_lat_list)
else:
    text_lat = ua_in_lat(text_ua)

print(text_lat)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Да, транслитерация должна быть официальная, согласно действующему постановлению Кабмина. Какие конкретно замены неправильны? Не уверен, что понял ваш тезис про наличие дефиса...

Comment: Про дефис я поспешил, а замены Вы исправили в п. 1 (там где буквы стоят на первой позиции).